# Combinatory method like tap, but able to return a different value?

Tags: ruby, theory, combinators

I'm going through a phase of trying to avoid temporary variables and over-use of conditional where I can use a more fluid style of coding.  I've taken a great liking to using `#tap` in places where I want to get the value I need to return, but do something with it before I return it.

```
def fluid_method
  something_complicated(a, b, c).tap do |obj|
    obj.update(:x => y)
  end
end
```

Vs. the procedural:

```
def non_fluid_method
  obj = something_complicated(a, b, c)
  obj.update(:x => y)
  obj # <= I don't like this, if it's avoidable
end
```

Obviously the above examples are simple, but this is a pretty common coding style in the ruby community nonetheless.  I'll sometimes use `#inject` to pass an object through a series of filters too:

```
things.inject(whatever) do |obj, thing|
  thing.filter(obj)
end
```

Vs. the procedural:

```
obj = whatever
things.each do |thing|
  obj = thing.filter(obj)
end
obj
```

Now I'm facing repeated use of a condition like the following, and looking for a more fluid approach to handling it:

```
def not_nice_method
  obj = something_complex(a, b, c)
  if a_predicate_check?
    obj.one_more_method_call
  else
    obj
  end
end
```

The (slightly) cleaner solution is to avoid the temporary variable at the cost of duplication:

```
def not_nice_method
  if a_predicate_check?
    something_complex(a, b, c).one_more_method_call
  else
    something_complex(a, b, c)
  end
end
```

I can't help but feeling the desire to use something *almost* like `#tap` here though.

What other patterns might I follow here.  I realise this is all just nonsensical sugar to some people and that I should just move onto more interesting problems, but I'm trying to learn to write in a more functional style, so I'm just curious what long-term rubyists have determined to be good ways to tackle situations like this.  These examples are hugely simplified.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, it seems that your use of tap to induce side-effects is anti-functional. Functional programmers and languages avoid or prevent side-effects. The point of tap is that it won't return what gets executed in it. Thus, it can be used two ways: debugging and methods that induce side-effects. The functional way is simply to chain methods together or composite them.

Comment: No risk, I'd like to talk theory, though I fear this thread would be closed if there's no direct question, however, given that `#update` would return a boolean, not the value of `obj` (which is beyond my control), doesn't tap solve the need for a third expression to return the original value?  I would like to understand more correct functional techniques :)

Comment: Ah, I see how I could change that: `update(something_complex(a, b, c))`, where I have defined `update` to do `argument.update(:x => y)`... though this gets more verbose as the update parameters need passing in.

Comment: Well, it'd just be syntactic sugar for writing a lambda and calling it. You could us it to change a value in the middle of a chain, like `3.tweak { |i| i * 2 } # returns 6` which is equivalent to `lambda { 3 * 2 }.call`. It would also let you create and use references mid-chain: `5.tweak { |id| obj = expensive_lookup(id); obj.ready? && obj.valid? }` which is equiv to `lambda { obj = lookup(id); obj.ready? && obj.valid? }.call`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Define `Object#as`:

```
class Object
  def as
    yield self
  end
end
```

And now you can write:

```
def not_sure_this_is_nice_enough_method1
  something_complex(a, b, c).as do |obj| 
    a_predicate_check? ? obj.one_more_method_call : obj
  end
end
```

Comment: Ohhh, your `Object#as` trick is definitely better (to my eyes) than the `assign; if..else..end` version. You could probably have an `some_method(a, b).on(a_predicate?) { |obj| obj.whatever }` too.  I may take your `as` and reverse it slightly, adding `with` to the caller: `with(something_complex(a, b)) { |obj| a_predicate? obj.whatever : obj }`. Hmmm.

Comment: @d11wtq: Indeed, the on { } looks also nice, it's usually better to call a method instead of concealing it with send(:methods) wrappers (the problem is you must give it name). Note that your with(x) { |x| ... } is in fact Ick's let: http://ick.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Ick looks interesting, though I suspect it won't play well with RSpec, since it has a `let` method of its own, behaving completely differently :)

Comment: I will accept your answer, though I'll give it another few hours to see if anybody else has any thoughts.

Comment: The `Object#as` method should totally be in the sources. So many situations where it becomes useful! (I asked about it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378890/ruby-reuse-value-in-a-block-without-assigning-it-to-variable-write-object-meth)

Comment: Found it! It is `BasicObject#instance_eval` method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval (though the name is ugly and `as` sounds much better!)

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger, `instance_eval` is different, it changes the context of `self`. `as` simply yields the object to the block.

Comment: Ruby 2.5 gets `yield_self` method which is basically the `as` implemented here. This is mentioned in @kuboon's answer also.

Comment: Maybe should edit my answer to also note it, being the accepted one.

Answer (score 14):

```
def best_nice_method
  something_complex(a, b, c).tap |obj|
    break obj.one_more_method_call if a_predicate_check?
  end
end
```

The magic is `break` in `tap` returns another value.

**new**

ruby 2.5 has `yield_self` which exactly you want.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890832/683157

Comment: Ruby 2.6 adds the alias `#then` to `#yield_self`.

Answer (score 8):

`instance_eval` can be misused for this purpose

`"this".instance_eval { |test| test + " works" }`

since 2.5 it is possible to use `yield_self`

`"easy".yield_self{ |a| a + " peasy" }`

*Read more:*

https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-yield_self

Comment: `yield_self` is now in [Kernel](https://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-yield_self) and also known as [`then`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-then).

Answer (score 3):

I found a method in the Facets gem that might be what you were looking for: [Kernel#ergo](http://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Kernel#ergo-instance_method)

So your original method:

```
def not_nice_method
  obj = something_complex(a, b, c)
  if a_predicate_check?
    obj.one_more_method_call
  else
    obj
  end
end
```

might end up looking something like this:

```
require 'facets/kernel/ergo'

def nice_method
  something_complex(a, b, c).ergo do |_| 
    a_predicate_check? ? _.one_more_method_call : _
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something like this and I like tokland's answer, but I didn't want to pollute Object for the small script I was writing.  Instead, I made use of `tap` on an array:

```
[something_complicated].tap { |s| s[0] = new_cool_thing)}.first
```

Comment: easier to `[bla].collect { |bla| "bla" }.first`

Answer (score 0):

```rb
class Object
  def apply_if(pred)
    if pred
      yield self
    else
      self
    end
  end
end
```

Typical usage:

```rb
      def rlrs_usage_by_group(group_id, date_range = nil)
        views = ContentView.joins(user: [:groups])
                           .where(groups: { id: group_id })
                           .where(viewable_type: 'RealStory')
                           .apply_if(date_range) {
                             _1.where(viewed_at: date_range)
                           }
      end
```

Your case:

```rb
def nice_method
  something_complex(a, b, c)
    .apply_if(a_predicate_check?) { 
      _1.one_more_method_call
    }
end
```

or even

```rb
  something_complex(a, b, c)
     .apply_if(a_predicate_check, &:one_more_method_call)
```