# Ruby: reuse value in a block without assigning it to variable (write object method on the fly)

Tags: ruby, enumerator

There are several situations where I'd like to apply a block to a certain value and use the value inside this block, to use the enumerator coding style to every element.

If such method would be called `decompose`, it would look like:

```
result = [3, 4, 7, 8].decompose{ |array| array[2] + array[3] } # result = 15

# OR

result = {:key1 => 'value', :key2 => true}.decompose{ |hash| hash[:key1] if hash[:key2] } # result = 'value'

# OR

[min, max] = [3, 4, 7, 8].decompose{ |array| [array.min, array.max] } # [min, max] = [3, 8]

#  OR

result = 100.decompose{ |int| (int - 1) * (int + 1) / (int * int) } # result = 1

# OR

result = 'Paris'.decompose{ |str| str.replace('a', '') + str[0] } # result = 'PrisP'
```

Comment: Maybe you should include the output, too.

Comment: This has been asked before but I can't find the question ...

Comment: Been adding the outputs. Thought it was straightforward. I'm sure something exists (or could easily be monkeypatched to every class) but I can't find it myself either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method simply yields `self` to the block, returning the block's result. I don't think it exists, but you can implement it yourself:

```
class Object
  def decompose
    yield self
  end
end

[3, 4, 7, 8].decompose{ |array| array[2] + array[3] }
#=> 15

{:key1 => 'value', :key2 => true}.decompose{ |hash| hash[:key1] if hash[:key2] }
#=> "value"

[3, 4, 7, 8].decompose{ |array| [array.min, array.max] }
#=> [3, 8]
```

Comment: The [tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) `Object` method almost does that...

Comment: And this post refers to it too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378890/ruby-reuse-value-in-a-block-without-assigning-it-to-variable-write-object-meth

Comment: Is it me or you've just posted your own question as a reference in the comment of the answer of your question referring to your question again which is mentioned by you in your comment as a reference to your own question and so on..?

Comment: Ok I realize now the mistake. :) I wanted to say that the question is related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878687/combinatory-method-like-tap-but-able-to-return-a-different-value/7879071#7879071

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger not really, tap returns the object, not the result of the block.

Comment: Object#yield_self was added in Ruby 2.5. It does exactly what decompose does when you give it a block, and as a bonus, it gives you an Enumerator over the object you call it on if you don't pass a block.

Answer (score 0):

It actually exists (I could not believe it didn't).

It is called `BasicObject#instance_eval`. Here's the doc: http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/instance_eval

Available since Ruby 1.9 as this post explains: [What's the difference between Object and BasicObject in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894817/whats-the-difference-between-object-and-basicobject-in-ruby)

Comment: `instance_eval` does much more, it evaluates the block within the context of the receiver.

Comment: What does it mean? At least it does exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Take a look at the example in the docs. `instance_eval` lets you inspect (and modify) the receiver's internal state.

Comment: Which the `yield self` doesn't?

Comment: No it doesn't. It just passes the receiver to the block.