# Difference between Kernel#yield_self, yield(self), Kernel#then and Object#tap in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Ruby 2.5 introduced `#yield_self` method.
Ruby 2.6 introduced `#then` method.

What is the difference between `yield_self`, `yield(self)`, `then` and the existing `Object#tap` method?

Comment: This question will probably get some traffic, as more and more developers ponder this. +1 for usefulness, -1.5 for presentation. Please spend some time and make it good quality. (formatting, grammar, punctuation, some additional info, etc.). This can be an exemplary reference question.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The difference between [`tap`](https://rubyapi.org/2.7/o/object#method-i-tap) and [`yield_self`](https://rubyapi.org/2.7/o/object#method-i-yield_self) is in what is returned by each of the two methods.

`Object#tap` yields self to the block *and then returns self*. `Kernel#yield_self` yields self to the block and then *returns the result of the block*.

Here are some examples of where each can be useful:

### tap

Replacing the need for a `result` line at the end of a method:

```ruby
def my_method
  result = get_some_result
  call_some_method_with result
  result
end
```

can be written as:

```ruby
def my_method
  get_some_result.tap do |result|
    call_some_method_with result
  end
end
```

Another example is initialisation of some object that takes several steps:

```ruby
some_object = SomeClass.new.tap do |obj|
  obj.field1 = some_value
  obj.field2 = other_value
end
```

### yield_self and yield(self)

If used inside one of your own methods `yield_self` would have the same effect as `yield(self)`. However, by having it as a method in its own right this promotes method chaining as an alternative to nested function calls.

[This blog post](https://mlomnicki.com/yield-self-in-ruby-25/) by Michał Łomnicki has some helpful examples. e.g. this code:

```ruby
CSV.parse(File.read(File.expand_path("data.csv"), __dir__))
   .map { |row| row[1].to_i }
   .sum
```

can be rewritten as:

```ruby
"data.csv"
  .yield_self { |name| File.expand_path(name, __dir__) }
  .yield_self { |path| File.read(path) }
  .yield_self { |body| CSV.parse(body) }
  .map        { |row|  row[1].to_i }
  .sum
```

This can aid with clarity where nested calls are being used for a series of transformations on some data. Similar features exist in other programming languages. The [pipe operator in Elixir](https://elixir-lang.github.io/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html#the-pipe-operator) is a good one to take a look at.

### then

`#yield_self` might feel a bit technical and wordy. That's why Ruby 2.6 introduced an alias for `#yield_self`, `#then`.

```ruby
"something"
  .then {|str| str.chars.map {|x| x.ord + 1 }}
  .then {|ords| ords.map {|x| x.chr }}
  .then {|chars| chars.join } 
  .then {|str| str + "!" }
  .then {|str| str + "!" }
  # tpnfuijoh!!
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @mikej

Answer (score 15):

Great summary of this here: [Ruby 2.5 added yield_self](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/12/12/ruby-2-5-added-yield_self.html).

Quick update: `yield_self` will have an alias `then` in new versions of Ruby, following requests from the community for this to be more readable.

It's a very good, concise read, quoted below for posterity. All credit to the original author, Vijay Kumar Agrawal:

> Ruby 2.5 added a new method named yield_self. It yields the receiver
>   to the given block and returns output of the last statement in the
>   block.
>
> ```
> irb> "Hello".yield_self { |str| str + " World" }
>   => "Hello World"
> ```
>
> **How is it different from try in Rails ?**
>
> Without a method argument try
>   behaves similar to yield_self. It would yield to the given block
>   unless the receiver is nil and returns the output of the last
>   statement in the block.
>
> ```
> irb> "Hello".try { |str| str + " World" }
>   => "Hello World"
> ```
>
> Couple of differences to note are, try is not part of Ruby but Rails.
>   Also try’s main purpose is protection against nil hence it doesn’t
>   execute the block if receiver is nil.
>
> ```
> irb> nil.yield_self { |obj| "Hello World" }
>   => "Hello World"
>
> irb> nil.try { |obj| "Hello World" }
>   => nil
> ```
>
> **What about tap?**
>
> tap also is similar to yield_self. It’s part of Ruby
>   itself. The only difference is the value that is returned. tap returns
>   the receiver itself while yield_self returns the output of the block.
>
> ```
> irb> "Hello".yield_self { |str| str + " World" }
>   => "Hello World"
>
> irb> "Hello".tap { |str| str + " World" }
>   => "Hello"
> ```
>
> Overall, yield_self improves readability of the code by promoting
>   chaining over nested function calls. Here is an example of both the
>   styles.
>
> ```
> irb> add_greeting = -> (str) { "HELLO " + str }
> irb> to_upper = -> (str) { str.upcase }
>
> # with new `yield_self`
> irb> "world".yield_self(&to_upper)
>             .yield_self(&add_greeting)
>   => "HELLO WORLD"
>
> # nested function calls
> irb> add_greeting.call(to_upper.call("world"))
>   => "HELLO WORLD"
> ```
>
> yield_self is part of Kernel and hence it’s available to all the
>   objects.

Please don't accept this as the answer, as it's not my own handiwork (and I'm happy to delete if anyone has any objections) - but I found this a very good read and thought it might help others at some point.

Comment: That reference is helpful, but a link in a comment would be sufficient and appropriate.

Comment: Cheers @CarySwoveland, I did think that, though the number of times I've followed a dead link meant me think it might be handy to be able to refer to this directly. As said, happy to remove if the consensus is for that.

Comment: I'd want this to stay. @SRack: you [could transform this answer into a community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), so that you don't benefit from the upvotes on the content you didn't produce :)

Comment: Good idea @SergioTulentsev - didn't know of that option. I've switched it over now. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add to mikej's answer on **parallelism between `each` vs. `map` and `tap` vs. `yield_self`**.

There are many question asking the difference between `each` and `map` for enumerables. The former is used for doing something with a side effect or something destructive, and then returning the receiver, which is handy for chaining methods. The latter returns the evaluated value in place of each element in the receiver.

`tap` vs. `yield_self` is just like this; the difference is that they are done for a single receiver object instead of elements within an enumerable receiver. So their use case would parallel what I wrote above. The former is used for doing something with a side effect or something destructive, and then returning the receiver, which is handy for chaining methods. The latter returns the evaluated value instead of the receiver.

Comment: Interesting perspective, thanks for sharing. Just like `map` can be more functional and elegant than `each` and I would use `each` less often, `then` can be more functional and elegant than `tap` and I would use `tap` less often (if at all).