# method cascading is possible here?

Tags: ruby

I have a three lines of code here like shown below

```
local = headers.zip(*data_rows).transpose
local = local[1..-1].map {|dataRow| local[0].zip(dataRow).to_h}
p local
```

Now if you watch the above three lines, I have to store the result of the first line in the variable called local since it would be used in two places in the second line as I have shown,So Can't I cascade the second line with first line anyway? I tried using tap like this

```
local = headers.zip(*data_rows).transpose.tap{|h|h[1..-1].map {|dataRow| h[0].zip(dataRow).to_h}}
```

tap is returning the self as explained in the document so can't I get the result final result when I use tab? Anyway other way to achieve this result in one single line so that I don't have to use local variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Ruby 2.5.0 or later, you can use `yield_self` for this.

```
local = headers.zip(*data_rows).transpose.yield_self { |h| h[1..-1].map { |dataRow| h[0].zip(dataRow).to_h } }
```

[`yield_self`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/Object.html#method-i-yield_self) is similar to [`tap`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) in that they both yield `self` to the block. The difference is in what is returned by each of the two methods.

`Object#tap` yields self to the block *and then returns self*. `Kernel#yield_self` yields self to the block and then *returns the result of the block*.

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890832/63034) to a previous question where I gave a couple of further examples of where each of these method can be useful.

Comment: Oppppssssss! I am using Ruby 2.3.3. But this is the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Very well explained!

Answer (score 2):

It's often helpful to execute working code with data, to better understand what is to be computed. Seeing `transpose` and `zip`, which are often interchangeable, used together, was a clue that a simplification might be possible (`a = [1,2,3]; b = [4,5,6]; a.zip(b) => [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]] <= [a,b].transpose`).

Here's my data:

```
headers=[1,2,3]
data_rows=[[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33],[41,42,43]]
```

and here's what the working code returns:

```
local = headers.zip(*data_rows).transpose
local[1..-1].map {|dataRow| local[0].zip(dataRow).to_h}
  #=> [{1=>11, 2=>12, 3=>13}, {1=>21, 2=>22, 3=>23},
  #    {1=>31, 2=>32, 3=>33}, {1=>41, 2=>42, 3=>43}]
```

It would seem that this might be computed more simply:

```
data_rows.map { |row| headers.zip(row).to_h }
  #=> [{1=>11, 2=>12, 3=>13}, {1=>21, 2=>22, 3=>23},
  #    {1=>31, 2=>32, 3=>33}, {1=>41, 2=>42, 3=>43}]
```